# What value does a bundler provide when publishing to npm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, bundler, npm-publish, tsup

For context, I've used Node.js for years, but this is the first time I've published a Node.JS package for others to use. Not knowing where to start, I googled for how to do this for typescript and [followed the steps in this article](https://pauloe-me.medium.com/typescript-npm-package-publishing-a-beginners-guide-40b95908e69c).

It recommended [tsup](https://github.com/egoist/tsup/) as a bundler. One of the things it does is output two versions of my project. One for CommonJS users and one for ESM users. I see the value in that.

**But what's the value in *bundling* that output?** Here are the best reasons I could come up with on my own, but I'm not sure if they're even valid:

1. Tree shaking. If I published my files as-is, any inaccessible code would be included in that package, increasing the package size.
2. This is a stab in the dark, but maybe if my package were published as loose files, users could `import`/`require` any file they wanted, even parts intended to be internal-only? (Up to this point, I've assumed the `package.json` `main` property enforces this.)

I guess I'm assuming it's possible to publish an *unbundled* version of my package, one for CommonJS and another for ESM. Let me know if that assumption is incorrect.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `Why would people being able to import only parts of your package even remotely be a problem?` It sounds like you are referring to my second bullet point. Can you word that a different way? I'm not sure where I implied that that was the issue.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hmm. I'm assuming you meant to say, "makes very **little** sense?" I can think of a few reasons why you wouldn't want people to use internal code, even if it were useful. 1) Imagine you publish v1 of a project that explodes in popularity. Later you find out a huge portion of users are importing your code that was intended to be internal-only. Now you can't change that code without breaking those users projects. 2) It might slow IDE autocompletion for users when every module in your project is available for import.

Comment: 3) Users might not be intending to import internal APIs of your project but are doing so accidentally. Hiding your internal APIs would guide these users in the right direction.

Comment: Regarding your original comment, I acknowledge that it can all be bypassed as long as it's open source. My point is there's value in *communicating* the intention of encapsulation, even when that encapsulation is an illusion.

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77804334/what-value-does-a-bundler-provide-when-publishing-to-npm?noredirect=1#comment137173250_77804334) is exactly the answer I was looking for. I will mark it as accepted if you post it. I do think it's worth pointing out that your comment applies to modern packages using newer versions of node.js. I also think it's worth pointing out why bundling *used to be* valuable for node.js packages (assuming it ever was).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I wasn't able to find any articles specifically about this in the context of node.js. Personally, I don't see this anymore opinion based than, "What are the benefits of tree-shaking?" If you feel like that question should be closed too, fair enough. Otherwise, I'd like to understand the difference.

Comment: Very well. Have an answer. And I've removed my other comments since those became moot.

Comment: Value is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @DanielKaplan remember to accept or upvote, otherwise what was the point of posting on SO instead of a general programming help forum.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry, was AFK for a few days. I have a follow up question (see my comment) before I mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling started life for the browser, before JS had any sort of modules or dependency management, and before Node existed, but really took off when React came along and went "what if you don't use JavaScript, but something that hides some of the downright stupid syntax you need if you write real JS, and we just compile that down to JS?" and unlike CoffeeScript, people went nuts over it and anyone who wanted to use React *had* to bundle their code because it had to run through babel anyway (when it was still called 6to5). This was also when folks went "well if we're bundling anyway, can we also just ..." and added dead code removal, asset hashing, auto-shimming, CSS compilation, multi target transpilation to the browser *and* Node, etc. etc. We even added things that used to be separate post-processing steps into bundlers, like minification (which was necessary for phones, which came with *megabytes* of RAM, so reducing a variable from `anchorManagerRouter` to `x` *actually* did something).

Of course: at the expense of completely destroying the browser's ability to cache data. A one character change somewhere? That's a completely new 1MB download, thank you very much.

However, JS grew up (or rather, kept getting worked on) and got a real module system, so that browser code didn't need bundling anymore, and could finally rely on browser caching again. "But now your download would be 20+ separate files!" is true, but the fact that *we got browser caching back*, paired with things like QUIK made that objection moot.

Bundling was still useful for generating universal libraries, but more and more people were generating separate bundles for separate targets, because they could be optimized separately, and to make a long story shorter: bundling itself is basically pointless today.

The browser doesn't need it, and Node, Deno, and Bun all support modern ESM code, so as long as your code's not tied to "the DOM" or "the filesystem", you're already writing universal JS these days just by writing JS.

And of course Node never needed it, UMD libraries were just a convenient "deploy one thing" solution.

Of all the jobs that modern bundlers like `esbuild` or `tsup` perform, the *bundling* is basically the one thing no one actually needs anymore, it just acts as a vehicle for all the other stuff you want or even need to do to your code, and makes all the other things like treeshaking (arguably useful, arguably not), minification (definitely no longer useful), transpilation (the main reason to use build tools these days), easier for the folks who write those tools.

So what's the value of bundling? Absolutely nothing. But what's the value of using a bundler that happens to output a bundle as part of doing everything else that *does* have value? Literally "being able to do all those other things". You could run all those tasks separately, yourself, in a large build chain. That's literally how all of this worked in the early days. If we weren't piping data from stream to stream because the folks working on Node liked streams a little too much.

(*This answer glosses over a *ton* of JS dev history. If you were a Grunt or Gulp fan, or you fondly remember requirejs, or Bower was your jam, or you were on the iojs side of "the split", or you remember anything else not mentioned here: this is not "the history of JS dev"* =)

Comment: `Bundling was still useful for generating universal libraries` Why is that?

Comment: Because they were universal? One file, works everywhere. Node and the browser weren't always as aligned as they are today, nor were IE and "anything that was actually compatible with the internet". There were some _pretty significant_ differences you used to have to shim.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that sentence as "Budling **is** still useful for generating universal libraries." I understand now. Thanks again.